# How can we change size of an attribute Swatch image in Magento2

Tags: product, magento2

How to change the `product swatch image size` in `Magento2`.

Is there any option to change *the size in the file `/etc/view.xml`* ?

Comment: @David Henry for magento 2.1 with the Porto Theme
what are you changing in
/vendor/magento/module-swatch/etc/module.xmlfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

Add the below code in /etc/view.xml file

```
<image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
                 <width>38</width>
                 <height>38</height>
</image>
```

Clear all cache types and check.

Answer (score 1):

for me this didn't work, but editing the following file did:

/vendor/magento/module-swatch/etc/module.xml

I'm using M2.1.2 with the Porto Theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in magento 2.3 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2978#issuecomment-171610891.

Updating to Magento 2.3 will resolve the issue.